# Ігоря чи Ігора?

Tags: власні-назви, відмінювання, орфографія, родовий-відмінок

На сайті "Как правильно?" є [суперечливе пояснення правильного написання імені *Ігоря (-а)*](https://kak-pravilno.net/igorya-chi-igora-yak-pravilno/):

> #### Правильно
>
> **Ігоря** — згідно з правилами сучасної української мови ім’я “Ігор” у родовому відмінку говориться і пишеться з буквою “я” в кінці слова — “Ігоря”. Написання цього імені являється виключенням з правил відмінювання імен, що закінчуються в називному відмінку на -р (Ігор — Ігоря, Лазар — Лазаря).
>   *Ми запросили Ігоря на зустріч*
>   *Ігоря покликали додому*
>   *Нікому немає діла до Ігоря*
>   *Запрошення для Ігоря Івановича*
>
> #### Неправильно
>
> Ігора — на даний момент такий варіант написання імені являється неправильним, але з приводу цього серед мовознавців ведеться багато спорів. Багато хто вважає, що форма “Ігоря” НЕ ВІДПОВІДАЄ сучасній українській мові і являється офіційно закріпленим русизмом.

(Виділення великими літерами моє.)

Comment: Коли розглядається лише одне джерело, завжди варто враховувати ймовірність банального одруку чи авторської помилки. Саме тому у нас прийнято перед тим, як ставити запитання, намагатися зʼясувати проблему самостійно.

Comment: @bytebuster, там немає одруку чи авторської помилки. Там просто автор у кінці стверджує, що частина людей (мовознавців) не згодна із переважною більшістю (офіційною позицією). Таке собі «хоча дехто вважає, що треба навпаки» в самому кінці.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Загальна українська — *І́горя*

Нормативно: *І́горя*.

Про це кажуть зокрема:

- [§ 103.2 «Правопису» 2015 року](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par103p2);
- [«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/);
- [Олександр Пономарів у своєму блозі](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/ukrainian/ponomariv/2011/07/post-49.html);
- «Словник української мови» в 20 томах (містить *[Ігоря](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%22+site:services.ulif.org.ua/expl)*, але не *[Ігора](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%22+site:services.ulif.org.ua/expl)*);
- «Словник української мови» в 11 томах (містить *[Ігоря](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%22+site:sum.in.ua/s)*, але не *[Ігора](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%22+site:sum.in.ua/s)*).

<sub>Тобто зміст зацитованої  статті загалом є правильним (незважаючи на дуже дивну мову, що використовується там — зокрема вжиток слова *являтися* у значенні «бути», [більш притаманний російській мові, аніж українській](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/2976)). А щодо того, що хтось із мовознавців вважає, що «форма *Ігоря* не відповідає сучасній українській мові» і є «офіційно закріпленим русизмом» — так між мовознавцями завжди тривають суперечки з різних приводів. Але офіційна норма (а також переважна більшість мовознавців і всі академічні джерела) поки що за *Ігоря*.</sub>

Тому що в загальній українській *Ігор* відмінюється здебільшого як іменник м'якої групи:

```
відмінок    однина                        множина
називний    І́гор                          І́горі
родовий     І́горя                         І́горів
давальний   І́гореві, І́горю                І́горям
знахідний   І́горя                         І́горів
орудний     І́горем                        І́горями
місцевий    на/в І́гореві, І́горю¹, І́горі¹  на/в І́горях
кличний     ???²                          І́горі
¹ — такі форми наводять «Словники України on-line» від УМІФ, але не § 103.2 «Правопису».
² — див. кінець відповіді.
```

## Діалекти — *І́гора*

Але в деяких діалектах ім'я *Ігор* традиційно відмінюють як іменник твердої групи (аналогічно до *Віктор*, *Єгор*, *Назар*, *Макар*, *Світозар*):

```
відмінок    однина                множина
називний    І́гор                  І́гори
родовий     І́гора                 І́горів
давальний   І́горові, І́гору        І́горам
знахідний   І́гора                 І́горів
орудний     І́гором                І́горами
місцевий    на/в І́горові, І́горі   на/в І́горах
кличний     І́горе                 І́гори
```

Тобто закінчення *-а* в родовому/знахідному, закінчення *-ом* в орудному і чітке закінчення *-е* у кличному. Це не можна назвати «зовсім неправильним», це (за висловом Anatoli Zhylavy, [коментар якого](//www.facebook.com/groups/367613903441695/permalink/954114388124974/?comment_id=954120368124376) наштовхнув мене на цю частину відповіді) радше «правильне в межах діалекту». Або ще можна сприймати як локальний варіант імені, що відмінюється по-своєму. Однак цей варіант не вважається нормативним.

## Про кличний відмінок

Джерела подають різну інформацію щодо закінчення кличного відмінку імені *Ігор*:

- Якщо вважати *Ігор* іменником м'якої групи (а саме так він нормативно відмінюється у всіх інших відмінках), то згідно з [§ 53.2 «Правопису» 2015](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par53p2) він мав би мати закінчення *-ю*. Такої самої думки дотримуються «Словники України on-line» від УМІФ (див. посилання вище: подають саме *І́горю*), Олесандр Пономарів ([у блозі](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/ukrainian/ponomariv/2011/07/post-49.html): «кличний відмінок — *Ігорю*») і Олександр Авраменко ([у відео](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvw5czJiE0Q): «у звертаннях використовуйте форму *І́горю*, саме вона відповідає нормам української мови: *Сергі́ю*, *Андрі́ю*, *І́горю*»).
- Чинний «Правопис» від 2015 року в таблиці § 103.2 (див. посилання вище) конкретно для слова *Ігор* подає закінчення *-е*. Саме це закінчення переважає в корпусах: [Grac](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/) ([386](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac&queryselector=wordrow&word=%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5) проти [331](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac&queryselector=wordrow&word=%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8E), причому останні впереміж із давальним відмінком), [Grac v.3](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/?corpname=grac3) ([397](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac&queryselector=wordrow&word=%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5) проти [377](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac&queryselector=wordrow&word=%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8E), причому останні впереміж із давальним відмінком), [MOVA.info](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx) (115 проти 19), Google Книги. Цій формі надають перевагу і більшість респондентів опитування, проведеного Інною Бойко в межах її дисертації (с. 259, діаграма В.5, див. посилання нижче).
- «Орфоепічний словник» Миколи Погрібного (Київ, «Радянська школа», 1983, 629 с.) на с. 247 подає обидва варіанти.

Я не можу зробити висновок щодо кличного відмінка. (1) Можливо, сприйняття *Ігор* як іменника не м'якої (а твердої чи мішаної) групи настільки поширилося, що вже впливає на форму кличного відмінка навіть у тих діалектах, де в інших відмінках все-таки вживаються закінчення м'якої групи. (2) Можливо, форма *І́горе* в «Правописі» — помилка; так стверджує зокрема Олександр Авраменко (у вищезгаданому відео); але ця «помилка» присутня в усіх версіях «Правопису» з 1993 по 2015 рік (окрім відхиленого проекту 1999 року) — невже таке можливо? (3) Можливо, праві й ті (незгодні із більшістю) мовознавці, що стверджують, що *Ігор* узагалі не мав би бути іменником м'якої групи, а віднесення його туди є наслідком росіянізації.

Тему кличного відмінка зокрема для імені *Ігор* докладно розглядяє Інна Бойко в її дисертації [«Функціональна сфера апелятивності у сучасному українському розмовному дискурсі»](http://scc.univ.kiev.ua/upload/iblock/fb4/dis_Boiko%20I.O..pdf) (Київ, 2017, УДК 811.161.2'366.542-116.3(043.5)).

Answer (score 7):

В правописі дійсно помилка. У [§ 103.2](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par103p2) слово Ігор справді подано у парадигмі відмінювання м'якої групи, і кличний відмінок мав би мати закінчення -ю, а не -е.
Але [§ 45 цього ж правопису визначає всі критерії м'якої групи](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par45IIp2):

> 2. М’яка група
>
> Чоловічий рід
>
> До м’якої групи належать іменники **чол. роду з кінцевим м’яким приголосним основи**: боєць, велетень, звичай, край, учитель, Бенедьо; сюди належить частина **іменників із суфіксами -ар, -ир**, які в однині мають наголос на корені: бондар — бондаря, козир — козиря, лікар — лікаря, писар — писаря, а також **іменники, у яких при відмінюванні наголос переходить із суфікса на закінчення**: буквар — букваря, вівчар — вівчаря, друкар — друкаря, інвентар — інвентарю, календар — календаря, кобзар — кобзаря, пролетар — пролетаря, секретар — секретаря, шахтар — шахтаря; гузир — гузиря, проводир — проводиря, пухир — пухиря та ін.

Як бачимо, немає жодних підстав зараховувати іменник Ігор до м'якої групи: закінчується на твердий приголосний основи, не має суфіксів -ар, -ир, і при відмінюванні наголос не переходить на закінчення.

Тому цей випадок потрібно:

- або вважати **винятком** ([§ 103.2 Примітка 2](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par103p2prym2)) і запам'ятати,
- або нарешті визнати його належність до твердої групи і застосовувати відповідні правила відмінювання.

Answer (score 3):

Правопис 2019 підтримує і наводе **Ігоря**. До того ж має деякі уточнини.

| відмінок | однина | множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *називний* | [І́гор](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=140) | І́гор-і |
| *родовий* | [І́гор-я](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=74) | І́гор-ів |
| *давальний* | І́гор-еві, (-ю) | І́гор-ям |
| *знахідний* | І́гор-я | І́гор-ів |
| *орудний* | І́гор-ем | І́гор-ями |
| *місцевий* | І́гор-еві (-ю, -і) | І́гор-ях |
| *кличний* | І́гор-ю | І́гор-і |

> [-ОВИЧ (-ЬОВИЧ), -ІВН-(А) (-ЇВН-(А)](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=28)
>
> 11. Суфікс **-ович** (**-ьович**) уживаємо тільки для утворення чоловічих імен по батькові: *Ві́кторович, Васи́льович, Іва́нович, **І́горьович**, Мики́тович, Олексій́ович, Ю́рійович*.