# when do plurals end in -і vs -и?

Tags: граматика, non-native-speaker, орфографія

I haven't been able to pick up the pattern of when plurals end in -і vs -и. Is there a simple rule, or a complicated one, or is it something I mostly need to learn case-by-case?

The [Ukrainian Lessons site](https://www.ukrainianlessons.com/grammar-plural-nouns/) says hard consonants get a -и (or a -а if neuter) and soft ones get a -і (or -я) - but it gives груша and море as examples of words ending in soft consonants, and I don't understand why that is. So far my understanding had been that anything with a ь, і, я, ї, є, ю or й was soft, but these don't have any of those - is ш or р inherently soft, or does е soften consonants the same way і does, or what? Or is the explanation on that page just wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Or is the explanation on that page just wrong?

Maybe more correctly: very simplified, therefore wrong.

Actually, thereʼre exceptions and Ukrainian has [three groups](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8_%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2):

- **Hard** where any word ends with any hard consonant except hissing: *ж, ш, ч, дж, щ*.

  Exceptions are *господь*, *звір*, *пазур* and *снігур* (and maybe some others) which are declined as a hard group except plural nominative: *звірі*, *пазурі*, *снігурі*. Some words are similar to previous exception group but have variations, like *щур* can be *щурі* or *щури*.
- **Soft** where any word ends with any soft consonant.

  Also any word with a neuter gender ending with *-e* which historically were mostly *-jo*. So the mentioned *море → моря* is here.
- **Мixed** which included mentioned hissing sounds. So the mentioned *груша → груші* is here.

---

But itʼs not all, because the hardest part for new foreign learners (and can be even [debatable](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3119/585) for natives) is *р* which can be hard, soft or mixed due to history where *-р* can be from *рь*.

Thereʼre many recommendations or kinda sorted groups. [Knowledge](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/-a%C5%99%D1%8C#Descendants) of some Slavic language or other languages can help, for example Ukrainian has *доктор* and *лікар* but: Polish *doktor*, *lekarz*; Czech *doktor*, *lékař*; therefore you almost know it should be *доктори* but *лікарі*.

Comment: Sounds complicated! The full wikipedia tables are a bit much for me, but hissing sounds being soft and р depending on linguistic history is great information. I do speak Polish (and only recently found out that rz comes from рь and that's why it's different from ż!) so I can use that context, which is very neat, thank you for including it!